# Cannot get ST_DIFFERENCE to provide required outcome in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, difference, intersect

Im used to using PostGIS to undertake a variety of functions, but for some reason am struggling to return the difference between two geometry columns [from different tables]. Assume it's me doing something wrong, but can't quite figure it......

I ostensibly have two polygons *test* and *tc*. *tc* is contained within *test*, but when I use the below code it returns *test* without the relevant *tc* removed....

I can't really mock up data as the issue seems to be specific to the geometry columns of the actual data - in lieu of such I have copied the data from the geometry column:

```
test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

tc = "0106000020346C00000100000001030000000100000008000000A0C36C35F4CF2041C0FFD4E8DFDD0641B0447216F3CF2041401F245D7CDD0641808B4A9BBCCF2041C0E14CEB88DD0641C8A30F2DBECF204180F4925CEDDD0641C85CCB39B7CF204140272842EEDD0641007590CBB8CF2041809B82FA58DE064100DC31C7F5CF204100742FA14ADE0641A0C36C35F4CF2041C0FFD4E8DFDD0641"
```

```
SELECT  ST_DIFFERENCE(t1.geom, t2.geom)
FROM    test AS t1, tc AS t2
```

Both are in the same SRID/CRS.

I have further tried linking the two polygons using:

```
SELECT  ST_DIFFERENCE(t1.geom, t2.geom)
FROM    test AS t1
INNER JOIN tc AS t2
ON ST_INTERSECTS(t1.geom, t2.geom)
```

Neither approach returns *test* with the the section of *tc* removed

Comment: You'll have to show us sample data that exhibit the problem, otherwise we can hardly help you.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz Albe - I've updated as best I can. I can't mock up data as it works perfectly on mocked data, but seems to be specific to my geometry columns. Could just be related to CRS, but both are reported as 27700

Comment: That's good enough. `st_difference` computes fine for these polygons; what is your problem with the result?

Comment: The ST_DIFFERENCE function does work fine on these two....however the actual data contains far more polygons-the second I add in a second polygon to *tc* I just get the original *test* shape...please see additional polygon ("0106000020346C0000010000000103000000010000000A000000A8604D2CF0CF2041C0E651094FDC064118AFBD27EECF2041009FFF81AEDB0641C07AE7C8D0CF2041000114C9B4DB0641084C6867CBCF204180F5D13CC2DB0641084C6867CBCF2041C0EDA534CBDB0641B017C8BFCCCF20418098AB5632DC064140C957C4CECF204180B921B5FFDC0641C85E426AF2CF204180267888F8DC0641C0DF474BF1CF204180892B23BFDC0641A8604D2CF0CF2041C0E651094FDC0641")

Comment: Sorted........realised I needed to ST_UNION the intersecting *tc* data. Thanks for your help Laurenz Albe